# Windows7 not share with Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, printer, network-shares

I have two machines
Machine(1):

- Windows 10
- 192.168.20.11
- File and printer sharing : Enable

Machine(2):

- Windows 7
- 192.168.20.12
- File and printer sharing : Enable
- Share printer
- connect Shared Drive on the server

Both machines are in the same network and in the same **subnet** and the same **domain**. If I try to open the shared folder in Machine(2) to connect to the shared printer in appear in the network. But when I press it the progress-bar and show me there is no user called Machine(2)!

[image: error message while sharing]

I access Machine(1) with another PC that has Windows 10 and no problem. I made Machine(2) share the printer and it works but sometimes the printer stops the share unless I remove it and reconnect it.

The question is why?

Comment: What if you connect Machine 2 with IP address to access the shared folder?  If you have SNMP enabled on the shared printers try disabling this feature and test.

Comment: I try to connect it with IP nothing appear SNMP already disabled

Comment: Now Machine(2) not appear in the share at all !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it solved it that was the  Windows update v.1709 it install new feature called **SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support** has three options  one of them was disabled I check it as the follwing:
1-click start button search for feature
2-search for SMB 1.0/CIFS
3-you will find it contain 3 option with checkbox make sure the three is enabled
[image]
and everything will go fine , this not the only cause there more for more information
    https://appuals.com/fix-cannot-access-network-shares-after-update-1709/

Thank to that guy for hint